# how to share player in google plus

Tags: google-plus

Hi iam sharing my swf player to google+.But its comming as url insted of player.[Click here](https://www.songdew.com/flash/songdewplayer_new.swf?plyr_songid=6428&Mybasepath=https://www.songdew.com/&MyTxt=Eclectica&MyImg=https://www.songdew.com/files/2510/tracks/waveforms/51d5167897bcd2db4fb7fd1f9db9e4.png&MyTxt1=https://www.songdew.com/index.php?option=com_music&cpanel=hide&view=display&id=6428%22) to see my swf player page

i try this below code for sharing google plus

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo  
rawurlencode('https://www.songdew.com/flash/songdewplayer_new.swf?plyr_songid=6428&
Mybasepath=https://www.songdew.com/&MyTxt=Eclectica&MyImg=https://www.songdew.com/files
/2510/tracks/waveforms/51d5167897bcd2db4fb7fd1f9db9e4.png&MyTxt1=https:
//www.songdew.com/index.php?option=com_music&cpanel=hide&view=display&id=6428%22');?>"
 onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'',menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars
=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img
src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the web, only uploaded videos through the Google+ interface OR videos that are hosted on specific sites such as YouTube or Vimeo will display as embedded players.

Comment: is there any chance that i convert that url as iframe in google plus...for demo see this web site once https://soundcloud.com/vanguard-records/country-joe-mcdonald-tricky%3Futm_source%3Dsoundcloud%26utm_campaign%3Dshare%26utm_medium%3Dgoogleplus